# When placing multiple charts in a chart sheet, how do I change chart properties using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to place multiple charts on a chart sheet by creating an empty chart sheet and then setting the Location of the charts to that empty chart sheet.

```
'This creates multiple charts within a single chart sheet!

Charts.Add 'Creates empty chart page when empty cell is selected

'Keep track of chart page for later reference
Dim chartSheet As String
chartSheet = ActiveChart.Name

.... 'Create three separate charts with data here

'Now place these charts within our empty chart page

Set chart1 = chart1.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=chartSheet)
Set chart2 = chart2.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=chartSheet)
Set chart3 = chart3.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=chartSheet)
```

All of the code works up until this point. The chart sheet contains all 3 charts, although the charts are all overlapping. When I try to adjust the position of the charts...

```
'This code fails to run!
chart1.Parent.Top = 0
chart1.Parent.Left = 0
```

The code returns a runtime error of *Object doesn't support this property or method*. I know it's possible to move the graphs manually by clicking and dragging, and I know that the above code works if the chart is within a normal worksheet. But for some reason, this code fails when the charts are within a chartsheet. Is there any way to get VBA to do what I want?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of Experimentation I belive your code isn't running because `chart1` is it's own worksheet.

When I drilled into a selected chart i've noticed the following difference. If the chart is embedded (Object in another sheet) the `Parent` is a `Object/ChartObject` which has properties `Top` and`Left` (it's relative location in the worksheet). If the chart is it's own worksheet, the `Parent` is actually an `Object/Thisworkbook' which does not have`Top`or`Left' properties. This makes sense because when you create a chartSheet the chart fills the entire sheet area and thus cannot have a relative postion.

If you insert a breakpoint on `chart1.Parent.Top = 0` and view locals.... you can see what I have explained above.

EDIT: to suggest something reagrding your ask in the comments.

The Children are contained in the 'Shapes' Collection of the worksheet object. i used the following to show the names of all shapes in a worksheet

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
    temp = temp & i & " " & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Name & vbCr
Next

MsgBox temp
```

From there you should be able to move and format etc.

Comment: I suspected as much. It makes sense that chart1.Parent doesn't refer to what I thought it would refer to.

I used your hint and analyzed the object model a little more closely. I think the way it works is this: chart1 belongs to the workbook itself, but the three charts that I want are actually *children* of chart1. If I can find the chart objects contained inside the outside chart, then I can manipulate the locations.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest a solution to looping through the children